# mvc kendo grid header text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

after looking all over the web, i can't find how to set the header text to the kendo grid.
for example instead of FName i would like it to sat "First name".
maybe one of you guys know?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FName).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShemIvri) ;
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShemLoazit);        
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable() 
    .Filterable()    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)        
     )
)
```

Answer (score 23):

You are looking for the `Title` method [see also in the documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI/GridColumnBase)

> **Title**
>   Gets or sets the title of the column.

In your case the code should look like this:

```
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FName).Title("First name").Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShemIvri) ;
        columns.Bound(p => p.ShemLoazit);        
    })
```

Comment: I can tell you how much i appreciate your help. I searched for this answer for 5 hours at least!

Answer (score 4):

or you can put [DisplayName("First Name")] in your model eg:

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]

        public string FName{ get; set; }
```